# Get next run from a text file

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to write a function in Java that returns the next **ascending** sequence (run) from a txt file, let's say the return type of a function would be *ArrayList*.

My example file *input.txt* contains next values: 78123421. So in terms of runs that means the file has 4 runs: |78|1234|2|1|.

What am I trying to reach here is like when I would call this function from main() four times it should print something like

```
1.run: 78,
2.run: 1234,
3.run: 2,
4.run: 1
```

or just two calls should print

```
1.run: 78,
2.run: 1234
```

I have tryed to solve my problem using BufferedReader/FileReader and RandomAccessFile but no working solution so far, please help :/

So this is what I have so far. The main idea was to use RandomAccessFile and read from input as long as **run condition** is satisfied. But the reader reads one value more, that is why I use seek() to start reading at the right position when next function call happens. There must be a bug in the code, because it doesn't print all the runs or just an Exception fires.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;

public class GetRunsFromFile
{
    static long start = 0;
    static long read_len = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
       File in = new File("C:/Users/henrich/Desktop/Gimp.txt");
       RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(in,"r");
       ArrayList<Integer> current_run = new ArrayList<Integer>();       

       for(int i=1;i<=4;i++)
       {
          current_run = getNextRun(raf);    
          printArrayList(current_run);
       }
      raf.close();
    }

    private static ArrayList<Integer> getNextRun(RandomAccessFile raf) throws Exception
   {    
      int v;
      String line;
      int val = Integer.MIN_VALUE;      
      ArrayList<Integer> run = new ArrayList<Integer>();        

      while((line=raf.readLine())!= null)
      {             
          v = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());            
          if(v >= val)
          {             
              read_len = raf.getFilePointer() - start;                  
              start = raf.getFilePointer();
              run.add(v);
              val = v;                      
          }

          else
          {         
             raf.seek(raf.getFilePointer() - read_len);
             start = raf.getFilePointer();  
             return run;                
          }
     }

     return null;
 }

 private static void printArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> al)
 {
     for(int i=0; i<al.size(); i++)
     {
         System.out.print(al.get(i) + " ");
     }
     System.out.println();
     System.out.println("------");
 }
}
```

For more questions please let me know.

Note: It should work only for ascending runs and files of any length.

Thanks for the support.

Comment: It'd be best to show the code you have got to try and pinpoint why there are failures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

## solution 1

For instance call your function with an int and make it return an int refering to the number of the last printed char.

Run Exaple:

after the first run return 2 cause the length of print text is 2
 after the second run return 6 cause the length of print text is 4 +2 from last loop... etc.

```
public int function(int startPoint){

// do stuff here

return lastIndexofPrintChar;
}
```

then call your function like this

```
loop{
int result=0;
result= function(x);
}
```

## solution 2

You can also dublicate your file and remove every String you print.

Comment: Solution 2 is not an option here but Solution 1 might work. Did you mean to skip already printed elements every time when I call the function or?

Comment: Yes. Call the function with an int 'skipChar' of how many chars to skip. After you do what you want to add the length of the String you print to the skipChar and return it. Then call again with the "returned" skipChar e.tc

Comment: I came up with solution that seems to work, but there is a bug I can't figure out. It happens when reading the last line of a file. ArrayList al contains the right value but the flow doesn't continue in else statement and printing out the last value. It either doesn't go to catch statement. Have any idea what the problem is? See my code below.

Comment: I think it's fixed now and the code is working as expected. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void getNextRun()
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/Users/henrich/Desktop/Gimp.txt")));
        br.skip(skip_lines);

        int v;
        String line;            
        int val = Integer.MIN_VALUE;        
        ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();           

        while((line=br.readLine())!= null)
        {
            skip_lines += line.length()+2;
            v = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());

            if(v >= val)
            {                   
                al.add(v);
                val = v;    
            }

            else
            {                   
                skip_lines -= line.length() + 2;
                printArrayList(al);                 
                break;
            }
        }

        br.close();
    }

    catch (Exception e){System.out.println("EOF");}     
}
```